# grep with Bash-Globbing-like search pattern

Tags: bash, grep, wildcards

I would like to use a very simple pattern matching with a `grep`-like command. Background is grepping a list of names of VMs, for example a commands that lists just the names of Virtual Machines, where I look for those whose name end with '.local'

Correct is:

```
# virsh list --name | grep '\.local$'
```

I would like to use something like

```
# virsh list --name | mygrep *.local
```

Character classes or range expressions are not needed, but the very basic patterns of shell globbing should be applied:

- `*` for zero or more characters
- `?` for just one character
- no extra marking for start or end of string, this is implied by start and end of the pattern
- no special meaning of the dot `.`

(for simplicity please ignore that bash is globbing for filenames first)

Comment: I don't understand, why would you want the much more limited globbing instead of the more powerful regular expression? The two commands you show (even imagining a grep that interprets globs) are not equivalent. Your regex, which can be simplified to `grep '\.local$`, searches for names that _end_ with `.local` while your glob searches for names that _contain_ `.local`. Which one do you want? Are you trying to avoid escaping the `.`? What is the reason you want globs (so we can understand what to suggest)?

Comment: Try it out: the filename glob `*.local` searches for files that _end_ with that string. The reason is quite simple: the String '*.global' is an option for a command which is used by users who are not always familiar with regexes. The strings I search for are always very simple, without the nuances that grep's extended regex were made for.

Comment: Ah yes, when used in shell globbing it is indeed the end. Sorry, I thought you were using it as a grep pattern. I don't think there is any tool that uses globs for searching though, no. I don't know of one and I doubt there is one since regular expressions are so much more powerful: why would anyone make a more limited tool if a better one exists? Isn't `grep '\.local$'` simple enough? You don't need `-E` and you don't need `.*`.

Comment: Seems like `python` could do it aswell with [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html)

Comment: Under `Correct is` should be `grep '\.local$'`, not `grep -E ".*\.local$"` as the latter is more complicated than necessary and using the wrong quotes. So your users are familiar with globbing patterns but not basic regexps - sounds kinda backwards. Regarding `without the nuances that grep's extended regex...` - your grep command is only using an extended regexp because you told it to with `-E`, if you just want basic regexps then just don't add `-E`.

Comment: You don't mention bracket expressions like `[a-z0-9._-]` in your question. I'd consider them part of basic globbing, if they should be allowed in your script then add them too

Comment: @EdMorton most people don't know what a regex is, but they have seen and used glob patterns on GUI tools although they might not know that it's called a glob pattern, so there's nothing backward there. Even I couldn't remember the silly BRE/ERE and always use the normal Python regexes. In fact most people use very simple globbing with the `*` meaning any characters and don't use `?` or `[]` at all because they don't know or don't care about them

Comment: @phuclv unless I'm misreading https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp or that's not what you're referring to as "the normal Python regexes", those are EREs. I see at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, though, that they might actually be PCREs which are far more complicated than BREs or EREs - if you can remember what those do you'll have no trouble with the far smaller syntax of BREs.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm referring to `grep -P`, and no I couldn't remember which characters in PCRE need to be escaped or not in BRE/ERE. I've learned PCRE first and after using it for a decade it's much easier to continue using it instead of learning the stupid BRE/ERE

Comment: @phuclv `grep -P` is for PCREs, you threw me previously by talking about python. If you're happy with PCREs, good for you, but obviously you can't write code that's guaranteed to be portable across all POSIX compliant systems using PCREs since there's no POSIX standard for PCREs and no POSIX tools that support PCREs. You may not consider the regexp standards that POSIX does define, i.e. BREs and EREs, to be "stupid" if you did decide to learn them, I've been using them for 40+ years and they seem pretty clear and useful.

Answer (score 7):

With the ast-open implementation of `grep` (also the `grep` builtin of `ksh93` if built as part of ast-open, which you can enable with `builtin grep`), you could define your `mygrep` as:

```
mygrep() {
  grep -xK "$@"
}
```

Where `-K` switches the regexp flavour from the default of basic regexp to ksh glob pattern (a superset of the ones supported by `bash -O extglob` for instance), and `-x` turns on exact match (the pattern has to match the whole line, not any part of the line).

In any case, you'd need to invoke it as:

```
virsh list --name | mygrep '*.local'
```

To prevent the shell from interpreting `*.local` as a glob so it's passed literally to your `mygrep` function.

If using `zsh`, you could however do:

```
alias mygrep='noglob grep -xK'
```

For globs not to be expanded in the arguments of `mygrep`, and then be able to do:

```
virsh list --name | mygrep *.local
```

That means however that you can't do things like:

```
mygrep *.local ./*.txt
```

To look for lines matching the `*.local` glob pattern in the `.txt` files of the current directory.

In zsh, you can filter elements of an array to those not matching a glob pattern with `${array:#pattern}` or to those matching a glob pattern with `${(M)array:#pattern}`. You can get the non-empty lines of the output of a command into an array with `${(f)"$(cmd)"}`, so here you could combine the two with:

```
pattern=*.local
print -rC1 -- ${(M)${(f)"$(virsh list --name)"}:#$~pattern}
```

Or as a function:

```
cmdglobline() print -rC1 -- ${(M)${(f)"$("$@[2,-1]")"}:#$~1}
cmdglobline '*.local' virsh list --name
```

You can enable the `extendedglob` option to get more advanced glob pattern operators (such as for case insensitive matching, interval repetitions, approximate matching, negation...).

Answer (score 6):

I quickly whipped up something with `python`s [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fnmatch
import sys

def main():
    try:
        pattern = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print('mygrep: No pattern supplied', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    results = fnmatch.filter([_.rstrip('\n') for _ in sys.stdin.readlines()], pattern)
    for line in results:
        print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Put it somewhere in your `PATH`, make it executable. Should do the trick, although it's a bit rough around the edges.

As mentioned in the comments, you will also need to quote the pattern to avoid filename completion by your shell.

```
virsh list --name | mygrep '*.local'
```

Answer (score 6):

As a bash *function*

```bsh
mygrep() {
    local pattern=$1 line
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == $pattern ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "$line"
        fi
    done
}
```

The `==` operator within `[[...]]` is a *pattern matching* operator.
Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

But, as @Panki says, you need to quote the pattern

---

A couple of others, just for fun

- [fish](/questions/tagged/fish)

  ```
  function mygrep
    while read --line line
      string match -- $argv[1] $line
    end
  end
  ```
- [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env tclsh
  proc glob_grep {argv} {
      lassign $argv pattern
      while {[gets stdin line] != -1} {
          if {[string match $pattern $line]} {
              puts $line
          }
      }
  }
  glob_grep $argv
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You say you want "globbing-like" syntax so it's not clear exactly what syntax you want to support but to deactivate BRE metachars you could just write `mygrep()` to escape all undesirable BRE metachars, change `*` to `.*`, maybe change `?` to `.`, and tell grep to match the whole line to get one definition of a globbing-like syntax:

```
$ mygrep() {
    local re
    re=$(sed 's/[.$]/[&]/g; s/?/./g; s/\*/.*/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$1")
    shift
    printf 'Using grep -x -- "%s"\n' "$re" >&2
    grep -x -- "$re" "$@"
}

$ mygrep '*.local' file
Using grep -x -- ".*[.]local"
```

You'd have to consider what to do with strings that already have escapes (e.g. `\?` probably shouldn't become `\.` and `\*` shouldn't become `\.*`) but without knowing exactly what syntax you want to support it's not worth putting more effort into this.

Comment: See also `printf 'Using grep -x -- %q\n' "$re" >&2`  or `(PS4='Using '; set -o xtrace; grep...)` to possibly get better quoting of the re so that it outputs proper shell code when `$re` contains `"`s or `$`...

Comment: As I said, I only have to work with very simple strings (names of VMs, usually [a-z0-9._-]). You're right, I should have been more specific. I'll update the question.